# Socket.io with VVV - Messages not being received on client

Tags: node.js, socket.io, vagrant, socket.io-redis, vvvv

I'm running VVV (Vagrant) with socket-io-redis. This seems to be working, the messages are sending to Redis.

I test with `SUBSCRIBE socket.io#/#` which is logging a bunch of messages for testing.

This is an example of the response I'm seeing in terminal -

`1) "message"
2) "socket.io#/#"
3) "\x93\xa7emitter\x83\xa4type\x02\xa4data\x92\xa4time\xb82016-04-03T22:17:21.478Z\xa3nsp\xa1/\x82\xa5rooms\x90\xa5flags\x80"`

Node JS -

```
var redis = require('socket.io-redis');
var io = require('socket.io')(3000);

io.adapter(redis({ host: '192.168.50.4', port: 6379 }));

// Handle opened socket connections
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log( 'Connection' );
});

var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({ host: '192.168.50.4', port: 6379 });
setInterval(function(){
  io.emit('time', new Date);
}, 5000);
```

Client -

```
( function( window, undefined ) {
    'use strict';

    var socket = io( '192.168.50.4:3000', {transports:['websocket']} );

    socket.on( 'time', function() {
        console.log( 'Received time' );
    });

    socket.on( 'connect', function() {
        console.log( 'Connected' );
        console.log( socket );
    });

} )( this );
```

When I run the Node app I see the message `Connection`, in the console of my browser I see the message `Connected` (then the socket for debug).

I cant' see anything obviously wrong, the client connects and the emitter seems to be working. But nothing emitted is ever received by the client.

Am I missing something? The IPs are not local host due to running Vagrant.

Any advice appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Quick update, I can emit without using `socket.io-emitter`, however it doesn't go through Redis. When I use emitter, it goes through Redis correctly, as mentioned above.

It seems as though my client isn't receiving the messages from Redis, even though the ports are open.

Here's what I try -

```
socket.emit( 'new_post', 'Nope' );

var io = require('socket.io-emitter')({ host: '192.168.50.4', port: 6379 });
io.emit( 'new_post', 'Yep' );
```

In my browser I see `Nope` but nothing else. I then `monitor` Redis and see the following -

`"publish" "socket.io#/#" "\x93\xa7emitter\x83\xa4type\x02\xa4data\x92\xa8new_post\xa3Yep\xa3nsp\xa1/\x82\xa5rooms\x90\xa5flags\x90"`

My server also doesn't see messages when using Redis, I test with -

```
socket.on( 'new_post', function( msg ){
    socket.emit( 'new_post', msg );
});
```

Comment: Can you include the Vagrantfile? would give better idea of port forwarding.

Comment: @Shishir I added ``config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3000, host: 3000`` and also tried the other port but it didn't make a difference. Would I receive the message "connected" if it was a socket issue?

Comment: @Elliott Did you try to emit on client to server?

Comment: @Elliott - were you able to solve it?